# Force MonoDevelop to 'Run Tests' under a specific runtime

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mono, monodevelop

A heap of our unit tests are failing under Mono on OS X with the following error:

```
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'System.Func``2' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

On of the unit tests in question:

```
[Test]
public void CanAuthenticateValidUser()
{
    const string testUsername = "jappleseed";

    var repo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    repo.Setup(x => x.GetByUsername(testUsername)).Returns(GetTestUser());

    var authenticator = new Authenticator(repo.Object);
    var result = authenticator.Authenticate(testUsername, "test");

    Assert.That(result, Is.True);
}
```

Running against Mono 2.8, with MonoDevelop 2.4.

Anyone got any suggestions to get around this?

**Edit:**

Should point out this error is coming from the inbuilt "Run Tests" command in the "Unit Tests" pad in MonoDevelop.

**Edit 2:**

Forcing the runtime as per jpobst suggestion runs in the console.  I guess the question has become how does one get MonoDevelop to exhibit run tests under a specific framework?

`shimms:Debug shimms$ mono ~/Development/nunit/bin/net-2.0/nunit-console.exe Convergence.Core.Services.Tests.dll`

Throws the same exceptions, however:

`shimms:Debug shimms$ mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 ~/Development/nunit/bin/net-2.0/nunit-console.exe Convergence.Core.Services.Tests.dll`

All tests pass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an assembly called "mscorelib", it's "mscorlib".  Is that a typo?  Or a broken reference?

---

Second try:

Are you sure your tests were compiled against 4.0 (dmcs)?

You can also try overriding the runtime with:

mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 mytests.exe

Comment: Sorry - its a typo, couldn't copy/paste from MonoDevelop - good pickup ;)

Comment: Its a library, but I added a console app, and referenced the test, invoked the test method form Main(...) and it ran fine.  Perhaps the "Run Tests" in MD isn't running under 4.0? I'll edit the question to be more specific about this.

Comment: Overriding the framework when running NUnit from the console works as expected.  I've updated the question again with more details.

Comment: Sounds like a bug needs to be filed on MonoDevelop.

Comment: Might also be an issue with my Mono installation - having weird issues with xsp now too.  Reinstalling, will re-assess after that.

Comment: I'll just run Nunit from the command line for now forcing the runtime version. Thanks for your help.